# how I can re-use a function

Tags: javascript

I am working on pagination. I took [this](http://code.mu/ru/javascript/video/implementation-of-pagination-in-javascript/) code like example.

The only thing I have my own function which create a product cart dynamically and I want use it but I dont understand how put them together

```js
function createNewElement(elementName, attrList, contentList) {
    if (attrList == null) {
        return document.createTextNode(elementName);
    }
    const element = document.createElement(elementName);
    attrList.forEach((attr) => {
     
        element.setAttribute(...attr);
    });
    contentList.forEach((content) => {
        if (content.length === 1) {
            element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content[0]));
        } else {
            element.appendChild(createNewElement(...content));
        }
    });
    return element;
  }

  function createRoomCard(data) {
    return createNewElement("div", [["class", "rooms__item-wrapper"], ["id", "rooms__item-wrapper"]], [
      ["picture", [], [
        ["img", [
          ["class", "rooms__image"], 
          ["src", `img/${data.img}`],
          ["alt", "Room image"] 
        ], []]
      ]],
      ["ul", [["class", "rooms__item"]], [
        ["li", [], [
          ["h2", [["class", "rooms__item-heading"]], [[data.name]]],
        ]],
        ["li", [["class", "rooms__item-description"]], [
          ["p", [["class", "rooms__item-description--list"]], [
            ["sup", [["class", "rooms__item-description--dollar"]], [["$"]]],
            ["span", [["class", "rooms__item-price"]], [[data.price]]],
            ["sub", [], [["/per night"]]]
          ]]
         ]]
       ]]
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pagination.js  plugin  for jquery
examples here https://pagination.js.org

put data in `DATA_SOURCE` array    then call  `.pagination`  on element with id list  i put 5 items per page here  `pageSize:5` then i made custom template for each item using `__createRoomCard` function

```js
function __createRoomCard(data){
  
       for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            data[i]=`<div class="rooms__item-wrapper" id="rooms__item-wrapper"><picture><img class="rooms__image" src="img/${data[i].img}" alt="Room image"></picture><ul class="rooms__item"><li><h2 class="rooms__item-heading">${data[i].name}</h2></li><li class="rooms__item-description"><p class="rooms__item-description--list"><sup class="rooms__item-description--dollar">$</sup><span class="rooms__item-price">${data[i].price}</span><sub>/per night</sub></p></li></ul>`;
        }
        
        return data.join("");
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
 DATA_SOURCE= [
 {img:'room1.jpg',price:22,name:'Card1'},{img:'room2.jpg',price:100,name:'Card2'},{img:'room3.jpg',price:55,name:'Card3'},
{img:'room1.jpg',price:22,name:'Card1'},{img:'room2.jpg',price:100,name:'Card2'},{img:'room3.jpg',price:55,name:'Card3'}];
  
  
  $('#list').pagination({
    dataSource: DATA_SOURCE,
    pageSize: 5, //here put number of items per page
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        // template method of yourself
        var html = __createRoomCard(data);
        $('#Z').html(html);
    }
})
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.1.5/pagination.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="list" ></div>
<div id="Z">Loading...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: also you can  add  style to make in one row

Comment: I dont understant why blocks goes inside each other? I didnt change nothing in your code https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502658536428

Comment: your link photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502658536428 takes me to photobox.co.uk   maybe it's deleted please re-upload image

Comment: i posted a question here, but so far nobody answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947791/pagination-using-jquery-pagination-plugin