# pagination using jquery pagination plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of an issue understanding the jQuery Pagination plugin. This is my first time using it. On my prev question one guy offered me this solution, but I just can't make it work for me; I don't understand why each next room goes inside the previous one. Here is a [pic](http://photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502658536428)

[image]
[image]

```js
function __createRoomCard(data) {
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    data[i] = `<div class="rooms__item-wrapper" id="rooms__item-wrapper">
        <picture><img class="rooms__image" src="img/${data[i].img}" alt="Room image"></picture>
        <ul class="rooms__item">
        <li><h2 class="rooms__item-heading">${data[i].name}</h2></li>
        <li class="rooms__item-description"><p class="rooms__item-description--list">
        <sup class="rooms__item-description--dollar">$</sup>
        <span class="rooms__item-price">${data[i].price}</span><sub>/per night</sub></p></li>
        </ul>`;
  }
  return data.join("");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  DATA_SOURCE = [{
    img: 'rooms_img_1.jpg',
    price: 125,
    name: 'Single Room'
  }, {
    img: 'rooms_img_2.jpg',
    price: 240,
    name: 'Standart Room'
  }, {
    img: 'rooms_img_3.jpg',
    price: 325,
    name: 'Double Room'
  }, {
    img: 'rooms_img_4.jpg',
    price: 450,
    name: 'Family Room'
  }, {
    img: 'rooms_img_5.jpg',
    price: 500,
    name: 'VIP Room'
  }, {
    img: 'rooms_img_6.jpg',
    price: 600,
    name: 'Suite'
  }]

  $('#list').pagination({
    dataSource: DATA_SOURCE,
    pageSize: 3, //here put number of items per page
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
      // template method of yourself
      var html = __createRoomCard(data);
      $('#Z').html(html);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.1.5/pagination.min.js"></script>
<div id="Z">Loading...</div>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: I added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi  my friend    please  add  `</div>`  at the end of  **data[i]**   like this

`</ul></div>`